# Замещение строки после выполнения скрипта

Tags: python, linux

Есть скрипт, который выдаёт определённое значение и после завершает свою работу. 
На данный момент скрипт выдаёт корректные данные в терминал, но использую функцию clear() терминал очищает себя и выдаёт новые , обновленные данные. Но происходит это с "миганием" строк, т.к.  clear() очищает строки и пишет новые.
Как сделать так , чтобы строки не очищались и писались по новой, а просто "замещались" , т.е. гладкая смена данных без миганий

Вот собственно скрипт

```
#!/usr/bin/python


import subprocess
import re
import time


def clear():
    subprocess.Popen('clear', shell=True)

def timeptprev():
    args = '/././././script.sh' + ' -d '
    for n in range(1,100):
        argspopen = args + str(n)
        cmd = subprocess.Popen(argspopen, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        for line in cmd.stdout:
            if "/home/" in line:
                print "Domain  {}   doesn`t  work".format(n)
            if not bool(re.search("[A-Za-z]+", line)):
                print "domain " + "{}:  ".format(n) + line

while True:
    timeptprev()
    time.sleep(1.7)
    clear()
```

куда копать?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте esc-последовательности 
http://citforum.ru/operating_systems/freebsd/ansi.shtml
Например перевод на одну строку вверх, на питоне выглядит как

```
sys.stdout.write('\x1b[1A\r')
```

возможно после понадобится sys.stdout.flush()

Comment: Не все терминалы — ANSI. По-хорошему надо использовать библиотеку терминала, на который осуществляется вывод, а также корректно отрабатывать отрицательный результат на вызов *isatty()*.